# Multiple date diff in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Now the only conflict left is when two endDates (10,15 in code) min value comes against the same startDate(25).

solution: I want to take min value out among those two min. values given by conflicting endDate.

```
 public class DateController : Controller
    public ActionResult date()
    {
        int allDiff;
        List<int> list=new List<int>();
        int flag = 0;

        DateTime[] startDate = new DateTime[3];
        startDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 5);
        startDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 7);
        startDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 25);

        DateTime[] endDate = new DateTime[3];
        endDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 10);
        endDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11,15);
        endDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 30);
        DateTime Min= startDate.Min();
        DateTime Max = endDate.Max();

        TimeSpan span = Max - Min;
        int total = span.Days;
        ViewBag.globalTotal = total;


        foreach (DateTime e in endDate)
        {

            foreach (DateTime s in startDate)
            {
                if (s >= e)
                {
                    TimeSpan span1 = s - e;
                    allDiff = span1.Days;
                    list.Add(allDiff);
                    flag = 1;

                }
                else {
                    flag = 0;
                }

            }
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                int m = list.Min();
                ViewBag.dhiraj = m;
                total = total - m;
                list.Clear();
            }

        }
        ViewBag.Total = total;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: 1: You must not write "NEED HELP" - everybody posting here needs help ;-) 2: Your question is a bit confusion. What do you really want to know?

Comment: i want to calculate MULTIPLE date diff...what not to include in that diff is overlapped days and gap b/w two dates..like startDate= 2011/11/05 and 2011/11/25 endDate= 2011/11/10 and 2011/11/20 output should be 10days

Comment: another consideration:: Overlapping...startDate:2011/11/05 and 2011/11/07 endDate:2011/11/10 and 2011/11/15 needed OUTPUT 10days

Comment: Can you edit the question and expand on the logic of arriving at 10 days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code

```
 public ActionResult date()
    {
        int j = 0;
        int output = 0;
        DateTime[] startDate = new DateTime[6];

        startDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 1);
        startDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 6);
        startDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 16);
        startDate[3] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 17);
        startDate[4] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 17);
        startDate[5] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 17);




        DateTime[] endDate = new DateTime[6];
        endDate[0] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 4);
        endDate[1] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 8);
        endDate[2] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 18);
        endDate[3] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 17);
        endDate[4] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 22);
        endDate[5] = new DateTime(2011, 11, 19);

        //5-7
                                               //7-9
                                              //15-20
        List<DateTime> start = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> end = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime interStart = default(DateTime);
        DateTime interEnd = default(DateTime);//initialize
        start.Add(interStart);
        end.Add(interEnd);



         for (int i = 0; i < startDate.Length ; i++)
         {
             if(i < (startDate.Length-1)){
              j=i+1;
             }
             else{
                 j = i;
             }

             if ((startDate[i] <= endDate[j]) && (endDate[i] >= startDate[j]))
             {


                 List<DateTime> intermediateStart = new List<DateTime>();
                 intermediateStart.Add(startDate[i]);
                 intermediateStart.Add(startDate[j]);
                 interStart = intermediateStart.Min();
                 List<DateTime> intermediateEnd = new List<DateTime>();
                 intermediateEnd.Add(endDate[i]);
                 intermediateEnd.Add(endDate[j]);
                 interEnd = intermediateEnd.Max();


                 if ((start.Last() <= interEnd) && (end.Last() >= interStart))
                 {

                         List<DateTime> finalStartValue = new List<DateTime>();
                         finalStartValue.Add(start.Last());
                         finalStartValue.Add(interStart);
                         List<DateTime> finalEndValue = new List<DateTime>();
                         finalEndValue.Add(end.Last());
                         finalEndValue.Add(interEnd);

                         DateTime finalStart = finalStartValue.Min();
                         DateTime finalEnd = finalEndValue.Max();


                         start.Remove(start.Last());
                         end.Remove(end.Last());
                         start.Add(finalStart);
                         end.Add(finalEnd);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     start.Add(interStart);
                     end.Add(interEnd);
                 }

             }
             else
             {
                 start.Add(startDate[i]);
                 end.Add(endDate[i]);
                 //remove(start.first);
             }
         }
        int count=(start.Count())-1;
        for (int k = 0; k <= count; k++) {
            TimeSpan span = end[k]-start[k];
            int diff = span.Days;
            output = diff + output;

        }


            ViewBag.finalOutput = output;

            return View();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do agree with the gents above on your question being poorly presented I believe I managed to understand what you are trying to do, replace your two for loops with the following:

```
//Create list of startdates that are greater than any of the end dates
//and return the differences in days
var list = from s in startDate
           from e in endDate
           where s > e
           select (s-e).Days;

//If any were found, take out the min of those
int dhiraj = list.Count() == 0 ? 0 : list.Min();
//Update total
total -= dhiraj;
```

Comment: @V4Vendetta It's a continuation of his own code where he defines total. As I said, this code block replaces only the double foreach loop